# Scala filter by nested Option/Try monads

Tags: scala, monads

In Scala, I have an `Array[Option[(String,String,Try[String])]]` and would like to find all the Failure error codes.

If the inner monad is an `Option[String]` instead, I can access the `Some(x)` contents with a clean little for comprehension, like so:

```
for {
  Some(row) <- row 
  (a,b,c) = row 
  x <- c
} yield x
```

But if the inner monad is a Failure, then I'm struggling to see how to pattern match it, since I can't put `Failure(x) <- c` in the for statement. This feels like a really simple thing I'm missing, but any guidance would be very valuable.

Many thanks!

EDIT - Mis-specified the array. It's actually an array of option-tuple3s, not just tuple3s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will `a.map(_._3).filter(_.isFailure)` do?

EDIT: after having seen the edit and your comment, I think you can also do

```
val tries = for {
    x <- a
    z <- x
} yield z._3

tries.filter(_.isFailure)
```

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly the simple answer I was missing by overthinking the for comprehension and match protocols. I had to add a flatMap at the start to remove the option (see edit).

Comment: Oh hang on... didn't see your edit... you had to do something like `a.flatMap(x => x.map(_._3)).filter(_.isFailure)`?

Comment: Exactly. I just needed to remove the option part. I think there might be a better way to do this with the Either monad, but it's working and I don't want to rework the whole solution to make it a little cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

In order to combine different types of "monads" you will need what's called a monad transformer. To put it simply, Scala doesn't let you mixin different monad types within the same for comprehension - this makes sense since a for comprehension just syntactic sugar for combinations of map / flatMap / filter.

Assuming the first one is always an `Option` then you could transform the `Try` into an `Option` and get the desired result:

```scala
for {
  Some((a, b, c)) <- row
  x               <- c.toOption
} yield x
```

If you don't really care about what's inside that `Try` that's fine, but if you do then be careful that you'll lose that information when doing `Some(x)`. If the pattern match fails, then you will get a `None`.

I hope that helps you.

Comment: I didn't think about that. Good point about the monad combination limitation. I do need the Failure contents, so this doesn't work for me, but it is very helpful to know. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest using a pattern match in that case, it's the cleanest solution :)

Answer (score 2):

This returns an `Array[Throwable]`.

```
for {
  (_,_,Failure(e)) <- rows
} yield e
```

Or, perhaps, an un-sugared version.

```
rows.collect{case (_,_,Failure(e)) => e}
```